# convert adb command to program code

Tags: android, adb

I know in android I can use adb command

```
adb shell getprop ro.hardware
```

to get info about android and I also use the follow code to get the same info:

```
String line = "";

try {
    Process ifc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop   ro.hardware");
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ifc.getInputStream()));
    line = bis.readLine();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
}

ifc.destroy();
```

so  my question if all the adb command can convert to program? And adb reboot recovery how to change to program code?